# How to make binary search of a stored array to be stable

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures

Here is the code for the binary search for an element in a sorted array:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int binarySearch(int *arr, int l, int r, int data)
{
    if(l > r)
        return -1;

    int mid = l+(r-l)/2;    //find the middle index 

    if(data < arr[mid]) {
        return(binarySearch(arr, l, mid-1, data));
    }
    else if(data > arr[mid]) {
        return(binarySearch(arr, mid+1, r, data));
    }
    else {
        return mid;
    }        
}

int main()
{
    int arr [] = {0 , 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66 };
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);     
    int data = 22;
    int index = binarySearch(arr, 0, n-1, data);
    if( index != -1) 
    {
          printf("%d" , index);
    }
    return 0;          
}
```

How can I make the search stable?  When the elements of the array are repeated, then my search should return the index of the **first** occurrence of the data in the array.

I want my modified code to produce as output:

```
input array is {1, 22, 22, 22}
output = 1, 
input array is {1, 12, 15, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 55 ,66}
output = 3
```

I can't see how to do that.

Comment: Your example doesn't compile (`data` is not defined within `main()`) and it doesn't `#include <stdio.h>` which it should (for `printf`).

Comment: `{1, 12, **25**, 22, 22, ..` is not sorted

Answer (score 3):

You would change the condition for a match from `arr[mid] == data` to the more complicated `arr[mid] == data && (mid == 0 || arr[mid-1] != data)`. Change:

```
    else {
        return mid;
    }
```

to:

```
    else if (mid == 0 || arr[mid-1] != data) {
        // note that arr[mid] == data is implied at this point
        return mid;
    }
    else {
        return(binarySearch(arr, l, mid, data));
    }
```

This still gives you O(log(n)) performance in case there is a large run of the searched-for value within the array (compared to some other simpler solutions, which degrade to O(n) performance in that case). You also keep the O(1) best case from the original search: that is, the result is potentially found without any recursion taking place.

Note that it does assume that it is ok to access the array outside the lower (`l`) bound iff that bound is not 0, whereas the original code does not make such an assumption. In the example you post, this is not a problem. If it was a problem, you could either pass the original bound down (as, say `ol`, and then `mid == 0` in the above becomes `mid == ol`), or instead use:

```
else if (mid == l) {
    return mid;
}
else {
    return(binarySearch(arr, l, mid - 1, data));
}
```

The latter loses you the O(1) best case, however.

Comment: thanks @davmac for the response. Cant we make binarySearch to do ' l' to 'mid-1' in the last 'else'  since we know that arr[mid-1] == mid. so that else case would be  return(binarySearch(arr, l, mid-1, data));

Comment: @viky scratch my last comment; yes, you can. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many equal elements you expect here a re two approaches:

1. simply go backwards in the list starting from the found element until you reached the first of the equal elements (takes **O(n)** n = number of equal elements)
2. search again in the subarray starting with index 0 and ending with the index of the found element. Do this until the new sound element has the same index as the one found before.

Here an illustration of version 2 (let each character be an element) and be seek for **B**

```
AAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCDDDDEEEFFFZ
^                                    ^  search range

AAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCDDDDEEEFFFZ
^                 !                  ^  found at position !

AAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCDDDDEEEFFFZ
^                 ^  new search range

AAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCDDDDEEEFFFZ
^        !        ^  found at position ! 
(different from previous finding position)

AAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCDDDDEEEFFFZ
^        ^  new search range

AAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCDDDDEEEFFFZ
^    !   ^   found at position ! 
(different from previous finding position)

AAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCDDDDEEEFFFZ
^    ^  new search range

AAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCDDDDEEEFFFZ
^   !^   found at position ! 
(different from previous finding position)

AAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCDDDDEEEFFFZ
^   ^  new search range

AAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCDDDDEEEFFFZ
^   !  found at same position as before => lirst one
```

Comment: This (second) solution also works, but is not the most efficient (although I think it is still O(log(n)) complexity, which as good as you can get). There is no need to reset the lower bound to 0; see my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Consider replacing `return mid;` inside `int binarySearch(int *arr, int l, int r, int data)` with the following:

```
for(; (mid > 0) && (data == arr[mid]); mid--);
return (data == arr[mid]) ? mid : mid + 1;
```

Comment: Certainly this works, but it degrades to linear performance in the (pathological) case where there are _lots_ of elements with the same (searched-for) value. It's possible to continue using a binary search instead.

Comment: (Also your code allows mid to reach -1, which would cause an out-of-bounds array access on the line with the `return`).

Comment: @davmac First, you are correct in the second comment and I've fixed the code. Second, you cannot continue with the binary search because you'll never know if there are duplicates of your value and you have to continue. Further, if you continue with binary search for 2 in the following array: `1 2 2 3 4` you end up with 1. And more, how can you know that this is the first value of the sequence? In short, I do not see any alternative to the linear search to ensure hitting the **first** element

Comment: see my answer for how to continue using a binary search.

Comment: @davmac You deserve your reputation. +1 for you from me

Answer (score 0):

Here I've changed your code so it checks every element to the left of found if it is equal to searched element, too.

```
    if(data < arr[mid]) {
        return(binarySearch(arr, l, mid-1, data));
    }
    else if(data > arr[mid]) {
        return(binarySearch(arr, mid+1, r, data));
    }
    else {
        while(mid && data == arr[--mid]);
        return mid + 1;
    }
```

But it can be slow if your entire array, for example, consists of same elements. Other solution is continuing search, but you need to keep in mind, that found element is valid and may be the only valid one, so you should never lose it on next recursive call (use `mid` instead of `mid - 1` or `mid + 1`).
Here is the code (sorry for changing the formatting).

```
   if (data == arr[mid]) {
        if (r - l == 0) {
            return mid;
        }
        return binarySearch(arr, l, mid, data);
    }
    if(data < arr[mid])
        return binarySearch(arr, l, mid-1, data);
    return binarySearch(arr, mid+1, r, data);
```

Answer (score 0):

With `<algorithm>`, you may do

```
int binarySearch(const int *arr, int l, int r, int data)
{
    // inclusive `r` for binarySearch
    auto it = std::lower_bound(arr + l, arr + r + 1, data);

    if (it == arr + r + 1 || *it != data) {
        return -1;
    }
    return std::distance(arr + l, it);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87efdfcd7f4dbc0b)